# Python program file move slows down process / make asynchronous file move?

Tags: python, file, asynchronous

Actually I use a Python program to parse xml files and write the content to a relational database (I split up by nodes and all the belonging elements). After each file is loaded I move the file to an archive location or an error location. But the file move command `shutil.move(src, dst)`  takes about 200-300ms and the loading process takes about 60-200ms. File size is about 5-20kB per file.
I select the files to process by following command
`xml_files = glob.glob('{}/**/*.XML'.format(path_incoming), recursive=True)`
How to speed up the process?
Can I queue the file movement, but then I need to consider the queued files to move to not reprocess them again in the files selection.
Any ideas or recommendations.
I have to process around 200000 files per day (with around 10 hours from a POS system) and the archive location is tar.gzipped every evening to reduce the number of files.
I just like to improve the throughput to have a better response. I thought maybe I can have a queue and process the queue with a second asynchronous process to move the files, either to archive or error location.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing for you to do is to wrap that up in a function and use

https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html

To map it across the different cores/processors and crunch everything in parallel.